# React Navigation Stack Navigator returning to the wrong route

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react native app and I'm using react navigation. Currently I have a Stack navigator (**MainNav**) Nested in a Tab navigator (**TabNav**) which is then nested in another stack navigator (**StackNav**).

When I press the back button in **StackNav** it brings me back to a route defined in **MainNav** and I'm not exactly sure why... Specifically, I'm on route **EDIT** and if I click back (on the **StackNav** back button not the **MainNav**) it will bring me to **LOGIN**.

Here's my code.

MainNav (contains a tab navigator):

```
const MainNav = StackNavigator({
  [INIT]: { screen: InitScreen },
  [MAIN]: { screen: TabNav },
  [LOGIN]: { screen: LoginScreen }
 },
 {
   headerMode: 'float'
 });
```

TabNav (Contains stack nav)

```
const TabNav = TabNavigator({
  [READ]: { screen: StackNav },
  [UNREAD]: { screen: UnreadScreen }
}, {
//options
});
```

StackNav:

```
const StackNav = StackNavigator({
  [MESSAGE]: { screen: MessageScreen },
  [EDIT]: { screen: PostScreen }
});
```

Not sure if this applies but each of these navigator have their own reducer and are each connected. Should there only be one reducer for all the navigators? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You mention reducers, does this mean you are using Redux or something similar?

Comment: Yup i'm using redux

Comment: I can replace the back button and define the route I wish to go to on click like this

`navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: <Button title='Back' onPress={ () => navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: READ })) }/>
    })`

Comment: You should add `redux` as a tag in that case since it can possibly complicate things. What does your reducer code look like? Is `navigation.dispatch` being called in them? When you say, "each has their own reducer" it makes me think that could possibly be the cause of the issue.

Comment: I think it might be better if you set headerMode to null, because you have 3 nested navs and the navigation header is not going to be easy to manage by default.